# How to replace token in circle.yml deploy command by environment variable

Tags: bash, sed, circleci

I have deployment section in circle.yml that looks like this:

```
deployment:
  default:
    branch: [prototype, staging, production]
    commands:
      - docker tag clever chaliy/clever-$CIRCLE_BRANCH:latest
      - docker push chaliy/clever-$CIRCLE_BRANCH:latest
      - sed -i 's/clever-registry/clever-$CIRCLE_BRANCH/g' Dockerrun.aws.json
      - cat Dockerrun.aws.json
      - eb deploy clever-$CIRCLE_BRANCH --profile default --staged
```

I have `Dockerrun.aws.json` where I want to replace `clever-registry` with value `clever-` + `$CIRCLE_BRANCH`. Substitution for $CIRCLE_BRANCH works in first two commands, however fails to replace anything in Dockerrun.aws.json file :(.

I also tried ${CIRCLE_BRANCH} syntax, but effect is the same.

May be there is another way to replace token in file? Or may be there other ways how I can substitute in that command in circle.yml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple quotes protect from environment variables expansion. Just protect your expression (if it needs to be protected) by double quotes:

```
sed -i "s/clever-registry/clever-$CIRCLE_BRANCH/g" Dockerrun.aws.json
```

that will work. In your case, seeing that other commands work unprotected, you could also not protect your expression at all. As long as `$CIRCLE_BRANCH` is not too exotic and doesn't contain spaces that will work.

```
sed -i s/clever-registry/clever-$CIRCLE_BRANCH/g Dockerrun.aws.json
```